# Using jq to select a parent by searching child key/value pair

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), how do I select a parent object if it contains a child object that meets two filter requirements?

In this example I want to select all Subnets elements that have a child tag with key "Name" and value "TheName".  My example has two subnets.  The first has "TheName" in the wrong key.  The second subnet has the name/value pair I am looking for.  i.e. `"Key": "Name", "Value": "TheName"`

The following selects a subnet with the specified value in one of the tags but not the pair.  It returns both subnets instead of only the second subnet.

```
jq '.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[].Value=="TheName")' output
```

How do I use jq to select only the subnets that have the name/value pair I am looking for?

```
{
    "Subnets": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-1234567a",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "IgnoreThis",
                    "Value": "TheName"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "NotTheName"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-1234567b",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "IgnoreThis",
                    "Value": "ignore"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "TheName"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
{
    "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
    "SubnetId": "subnet-1234567b",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "IgnoreThis",
            "Value": "ignore"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "TheName"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Like most well-written Unix commands, `jq` can read a file name argument, so that [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming your jq has `any/2`, a simple and efficient solution would be:

```
.Subnets[]
| select( any (.Tags[]; .Key == "Name" and .Value == "TheName") )
```

This produces the output you want, so I won't repeat it here.

If your jq does not have `any/2`, I'd suggest upgrading, but if that's inconvenient or not an option, you could use this def:

```
def any(f;g): reduce f as $i (false; . or ($i|g));
```

p.s. `any(str; cond)` can be read as: 'Is there any element, e, in the stream, str, such that `e|cond` has a value other than `null` or `false`?'

Comment: Awesome peak!  I didn't understand the docs on "any".  The docs and examples on jq are not super clear.  It needs more examples like this.  Hopefully the question title will help someone else find your response!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses [indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#indices(s))

```
.Subnets[] | select(.Tags | indices({Key:"Name", Value:"TheName"}) != [])
```